# Echo clean text in PHP with htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, html, textarea, echo, htmlspecialchars

I have a user form where i give the user the possibility to enter a text in a textarea and to change the text later.

Here is my example for the HTML textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="answer_text" type="text">
<?php echo strip_tags(nl2br(htmlspecialchars($answers['answer_text']))); ?>
</textarea>
```

- Text Input: `"This is  text"`.
- Text Output (echo): `&quot;This is  text&quot;`.
- Desired / Expected output: `"This is  text"`.

To avoid `<br>` in the echo i use: `strip_tags()`
To show line breaks i use: `nl2br()`
For security reasons i use `htmlspecialchars()`

How ever, if the user uses quotation marks (" or "") in his text i get `&quot;` in my text echo. I can solve this by removing `htmlspecialchars()` but i think its important to use it here. Is there any chance to get the correct output means the quotation marks shown instead of `&quot;`?

**EDIT:** 
I was using two times `htmlspecialchars()`. Once during getting the users input value by `$_POST = htmlspecialchars($value)` to send it to the table and as second during the HTML echo as shown above.

As explained by @Cbroe the problem occurred because the data got encoded twice. Initial it " became &quote; first - and then, during the second encoding, the & of that, got turned into `&amp;`.

Right way is in my case that i do not use `htmlspecialchars()` during SQL `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (i am Using PDO prepared statements) and to only use `htmlspecialchars()` during the HTML echo depending on the situation.

Comment: why do you think you need htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: May be i missunderstood the function but it is needed to avoid a user can bring some code into my data base (SQL Injection). The text was inserted by using PHP PDO Query.

Comment: You could also prepare your data via PDO instead

Comment: Yes, you most definitely have misunderstood. Databases do not talk HTML, so do not need things to be HTML escaped, or tag stripped. They need **SQL** escaping - or, much better, separation of data from query using parameterized prepared queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/157957 HTML escaping should be used when **displaying** data on the browser; it should happen **exactly once**, otherwise you'll end up with garbage like `&amp;amp;amp;` where the same string has been escaped multiple times.

Comment: OK understood. To summarize it and please confirm me if i got it now:
If i use prepared statements for INSERT/UPDATE and also later for SELECT there is no need to use on some point htmlspecialchars().

Comment: Of course there is a point for using htmlspecialchars, when you are actually creating HTML output - which you are doing, in the code you have shown. Imagine what would happen, if the _text_ I entered into this form, was `foobar </textarea> baz`, what would your resulting HTML code look like then, if you did _not_ apply any form of escaping?

Comment: _“Is there any chance to get the correct output means the quotation marks shown instead of &quot;?”_ - have you actually _read_ the manual for `htmlspecialchars` …? Doesn’t sound like it, so I suggest you go and do that now. How you can influence whether quotes are converted to HTML entities or not, is explained in there in sufficient detail!

Comment: @CBroe sure i did but i recognized now that i have used on two positions `htmlspecialchars`. I have it already in my `INSERT`/`UPDATE` query where i get the `$_POST` values from the user. I will leave it there and will remove it from the echo so i am fine.

Comment: No, that is not “fine”, that is exactly the wrong way around. Using it in the database insert portion was simply wrong to begin with.

Comment: Well i understand where are you coming from. It because to "clear" the echo or "clear" whats displayed. Absolutely understood. But is it making a difference at the and technically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229160/discussion-between-mischa-milivoje-bakic-and-cbroe).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use htmlentities()  instead of htmlspecialchars().
Like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="answer_text" type="text">
<?php echo strip_tags(nl2br(htmlentities($answers['answer_text']))); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hey, great answer. Try leaving an example with code for better understanding.